# How to get all the rows from DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in my WPF application, I want to get all the row values in a list in a button click. I tried some ways but I get the last row values only...

```
private async void Save_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pojo rowdata = new pojo();
    int rowcount = calendarmstrDG.Items.Count;
    List<pojo> pojolist = new List<pojo>();
    var rows = (calendarmstrDG).SelectedItems;
    for (int i = 1; i < rowcount - 1; i++)
    {
        pojo sda = (pojo)calendarmstrDG.SelectedItems;
        pojolist.Add(sda);
    }
}
```

Here calendarmstrDG is my datagrid name ...
pojo is my model class name ...

```
public class pojo
{
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Quarter { get; set; }
    public int SerialNo { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string PeriodName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: 1. You are only accessing the selected items, is that intended? 2. In your for-loop you are not using your "i" to select row by row

Comment: Help me with exact code..I want all the rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iterate over all items using `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(pojo p in calendarmstrDG.Items)
{
   // do something with "p", e.g. access properties: p.SerialNo 
}
```

DataGrid.Items collection contains elements of type `object`, so in `foreach` loop we have to specify exact type `pojo` to be able to access properties

if you need to get a new list of `pojo`, it can be done with Linq:

```
List<pojo> list = calendarmstrDG.Items.OfType<pojo>().ToList();
```

Comment: @Markz, you can perform operation with a single item in foreach loop, or you can get a list and iterate a list. I gave two examples

Comment: @Markz the whole WebAPI topic is not part of your question (and it shouldn't since it's a different requirement), so please don't expect answers that involve WebAPI and please don't expect answers that 'guide you somewhere' - if you ask a good focused question, you can get a good focused answer (like the two that you got already). If you need general guidance, then a Question+Answer website like stackoverflow is the wrong place.

Comment: @ASh thanks for your guidance ...I got the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ObservableCollection` to bind the data to DataGrid and you can retrieve the data using it without any effort. Something like this :

```
Class MyClass
{
    ObservableCollection<pojo> myCollection {get;set;}
    MyClass()
    {
        calendarmstrDG.DataContext = myCollection;
    }
    public void AddData()
    {
        myCollection.Add(new pojo(){ // Add Values });
    }
    public void Save_Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(pojo items in myCollection)
        {
            // here get items using items.Prefix/year/....
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Markz You cannot ask the question here in the comments. If you want you can ask as a different question stating extension to this question, along with the code what you tried....