# How to iterate through DataGrid items and insert them into database WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am developing a Point of sale app in WPF C# where I have a datagrid where the user adds a list of items to be purchased. The problem is that after adding these items to the SalesRegister datagrid, I am unable to insert these items into a database. I have searched the internet for solutions but the ones I find are solutions for WinForms DataGridView. I want to be able ti iterate through the list of items and insert into database. Here is a sample of my code and a screen capture of the interface.

[image: screen capture]

The code is shown below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgSalesRegister.Items.Count; i++)
{
    using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into SalesProduct(item_name,qty,price,total)values(@itmName,@qty,@price,@total)", cs);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itmName", dgSalesRegister.Rows[i].cells[2].value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", dgSalesRegister.Rows[i].cells[3].value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", dgSalesRegister.Rows[i].cells[4].value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", dgSalesRegister.Rows[i].cells[5].value);

        cs.Open();
        int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (a > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have successfully added a new item", "Information", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Item addition failed!", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
        Clear();
    }
}
```

This code works for WinForms DataGridView, but I need assistance for WPF DataGrid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all the rows from DataGrid in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862926/how-to-get-all-the-rows-from-datagrid-in-wpf)

Comment: Could be a bit late for you BUT you should be using MVVM. Bind an observablecollection<SalesItemVM> to itemssource of the datagrid. SalesItemVM being a viewmodel holds data for each item. In order to commit to the database you work with that collection. Work with data directly rather than UI objects to find the data they have in them.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I succeeded in using this code, but the problem is that it will only insert the first row values. I don't know how to insert all the added rows.   foreach (SalesRegister s in dgSalesRegister.Items)
                {
                    using (SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection(conn))
                    {
                        cs.Open();
                        
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itmName", s.ItemName);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", s.Qty);

Comment: @ChijiokeChinedu Could you update your question with the code that you're using now (the one that only inserts the first row)?